# Rails: Handling different gem versions for different operating systems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

My Rails 6 project uses some gems that install the [`grpc` gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/grpc/versions). In my Gemfile.lock, the gem is installed like this:

```
grpc (1.32.0)
  google-protobuf (~> 3.13)
  googleapis-common-protos-types (~> 1.0)
```

One of the people on the team has a Mac. When they run `bundle install`, it installs the OS X specific version of the gem in addition to the version above, so the Gemfile.lock will look like this:

```
grpc (1.32.0)
  google-protobuf (~> 3.13)
  googleapis-common-protos-types (~> 1.0)
grpc (1.32.0-universal-darwin)
  google-protobuf (~> 3.13)
  googleapis-common-protos-types (~> 1.0)
```

Other Gemfile information:

```
PLATFORMS
  ruby

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.5.7p206

BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.1
```

My local and production servers run Linux. When I attempt to run `bundle install` on my local environment with this in the Gemfile.lock, the `bundle install` exits with a `Killed` message, presumably because the gem is incompatible with my OS.

I've tried adding the gem to my Gemfile directly like this:

```
gem 'grpc', '1.32.0'
```

But that seems to only work sometimes, weirdly enough. How can I update the Gemfile to not install the OS X version of the gem and use the base version instead?

Comment: What is your `bundler` version ? And can you include the `platforms` enabled in you `Gemfile.lock`

Comment: @MonithShah Yes, just added to the original post. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Alexander `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux` in linux system then commit `Gemfile.lock` changes, it may fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone running into this. This was a known bug that was fixed in bundler version `v2.2.11`

From: [How to change the version of bundler used in Cloud Functions deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66565897/how-to-change-the-version-of-bundler-used-in-cloud-functions-deployment)

This is bundler's regression since bundler v2.2.8. https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/4366

Fix is here:  https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/pull/3655

Comment: Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

I tested on my Mac: `macOS 10.15.7`, `Ruby 2.7.2`, `bundler 2.1.4`

```rb
# Gemfile
gem 'grpc'

# Gemfile.lock
grpc (1.35.0)
      google-protobuf (~> 3.14)
      googleapis-common-protos-types (~> 1.0)

# bundle install log
Fetching grpc 1.35.0 (universal-darwin)
Installing grpc 1.35.0 (universal-darwin)
```

I don't have `grpc (1.35.0-universal-darwin)` in generated `Gemfile.lock`.

From the install log, my version of `bundler` will select proper version based on OS version, so you can't control it from `Gemfile`.

So few possible solutions are:

1. Your colleagues who use Mac could try **update** `bundler` if they use older version of `bundler`.
2. Remove `grpc (1.35.0-universal-darwin)` related code from `Gemfile.lock`, and tell your colleagues who use Mac don't commit that to git again (If solution 1 doesn't work).

Comment: Thank you! I'll try finding out more about the colleague's environment. We've been doing solution #2 but it's a bit of a hassle for both of us and would be worse if we're in a situation with multiple colleagues with Macs.