# How to change the version of bundler used in Cloud Functions deployment?

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

## Context

Deployments to Cloud Functions have been failing since a few days ago.

### Gemfile

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

ruby "~> 2.7.0"

git_source(:github) {|repo_name| "https://github.com/#{repo_name}" }

gem "google-cloud-firestore"
```

### Deployment script

```
$ gcloud functions deploy my_func --region=us-central1 --memory=128MB --runtime=ruby27

(snip)

ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler found conflicting requirements for the Ruby version:
  In Gemfile:
    Ruby (~> 2.7.0)

    google-cloud-firestore was resolved to 2.4.1, which depends on
      google-cloud-firestore-v1 (~> 0.0) was resolved to 0.4.0, which depends on
        gapic-common (~> 0.3) was resolved to 0.4.0, which depends on
google-protobuf (~> 3.15, >= 3.15.2) was resolved to 3.15.5, which
depends on
            Ruby (< 3.1.dev, >= 2.3)

    google-cloud-firestore was resolved to 2.4.1, which depends on
      google-cloud-firestore-v1 (~> 0.0) was resolved to 0.4.0, which depends on
        gapic-common (~> 0.3) was resolved to 0.4.0, which depends on
          grpc (~> 1.36) was resolved to 1.36.0, which depends on
            Ruby (< 3.1.dev, >= 2.4); Error ID: af32a539
```

## Why?

This is bundler's regression since bundler v2.2.8.

- https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/4366

And this is fixed at bundler v2.2.10

- https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/bundler/CHANGELOG.md#2210-february-15-2021
- https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/pull/4371

So I want the bundler version to be less than v2.2.8 or more than v2.2.10.

Cloud Functions deployment ( `gcloud functions deploy` ) automatically runs `bundle install` and uses `bundler` which installed in deployment task.

Current bundler version in deployment task is v2.2.9

### Verification code

#### Gemfile

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

ruby "~> 2.7.0"

git_source(:github) {|repo_name| "https://github.com/#{repo_name}" }


gem "bundler", "!= 2.2.8", "!= 2.2.9"
```

#### Deployment script

```
$ gcloud functions deploy my_func --region=us-central1 --memory=128MB --runtime=ruby27

(snip)

Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    bundler (!= 2.2.8, != 2.2.9)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (2.2.9)
```

## Main subject

`gcloud functions deploy` doesn't have some arguments to change bundler version...

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy?hl=ja

How to change the version of bundler used in Cloud Functions deployment?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue as well, however the error output was slightly different. One thing in common was the line:

```
Bundler found conflicting requirements for the Ruby version:
```

After doing some digging and troubleshooting, I found that Google Cloud Functions locks the bundled platform on our behalf. I'm not a ruby expert, but I suspect this will impact how information from the Gemfile will be read along with the Ruby version.

*Example Log from Google Cloud Functions*:

```
2021-03-10 13:13:01.764 PST
Step #4 - "builder": Done "bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux"
```

**Solution**:
Update bundler locally (I updated to 2.2.14). Delete your `Gemfile.lock` file and rerun `bundle install` to generate `Gemfile.lock`. This should fix dependencies if there is anything to fix.

Most importantly, it will update the `Platforms` section in your `Gemfile.lock` to match what Google expects.

In my case, the platform was updated from `Ruby` to `x86_64-darwin-19`.

Or the other approach may be to just update the platform with bundle if possible.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Eventually I have successfully deployed!

Comment: No problem, glad that you were able to successfully deploy!

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I have successfully deployed with followings.

1. `gem install bundler --no-doc`
2. Delete `Gemfile.lock`
3. re-create `Gemfile.lock` ( `bundle install` )

## diff

```
$ git --no-pager diff main

diff --git a/Gemfile.lock b/Gemfile.lock
index 5e7502b..b5642ab 100644
--- a/Gemfile.lock
+++ b/Gemfile.lock
@@ -57,7 +57,6 @@ GEM
       gapic-common (~> 0.3)
       google-cloud-errors (~> 1.0)
       grpc-google-iam-v1 (>= 0.6.10, < 2.0)
-    google-protobuf (3.15.5)
     google-protobuf (3.15.5-universal-darwin)
     googleapis-common-protos (1.3.11)
       google-protobuf (~> 3.14)
@@ -72,9 +71,6 @@ GEM
       multi_json (~> 1.11)
       os (>= 0.9, < 2.0)
       signet (~> 0.14)
-    grpc (1.36.0)
-      google-protobuf (~> 3.14)
-      googleapis-common-protos-types (~> 1.0)
     grpc (1.36.0-universal-darwin)
       google-protobuf (~> 3.14)
       googleapis-common-protos-types (~> 1.0)
@@ -160,7 +156,6 @@ GEM

 PLATFORMS
   ruby
-  x86_64-darwin-17

 DEPENDENCIES
   dotenv
@@ -180,4 +175,4 @@ RUBY VERSION
    ruby 2.7.2p137

 BUNDLED WITH
-   2.1.4
+   2.2.14
```